# Update cell value for each record

Tags: mysql

I want to update a cell value of each record like,

I have user table in which there is an email field which is unique, I want to update all record's email fields.

Something like this:

```
update user set email='abdullah+00(i)@gmail.com'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is `i` part of the table?

Comment: No i is not part of table.

Comment: is `i` another column?

Comment: No, i is not another column.

Comment: I want to fill email column values like:  abdullah+001@gmail.com,abdullah+002@gmail.com,abdullah+003@gmail.com etc.

Comment: When `i` is 10, should it be `abdullah+0010` or `abdullah+010`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE user
JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) var
SET email = CONCAT('abdullah+', LPAD(@i := @i + 1, 3, '0'), '@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string concat

```
update user set email=concat('abdullah',LPAD(i,3,'0'),'@gmail.com');
```

EDiT if `i` is not a column

```
update user (SELECT @i := 1) m  set email=concat('abdullah',LPAD(@i=@i+1,3,0),'@gmail.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:-

```
update user
(SELECT @i := 1) m 
set email=CONCAT('abdullah+' , LPAD(@i := @i + 1, 3, '0') , '@gmail.com')
```

I assumed that `i` is a counter

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
while c<10 do  // or the number of fields you have
update user set email = CONCAT('abdullah+00',i,'@gmail.com')
```